# Sorting with Spring Data JPA - Custom Repository

Tags: hibernate, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I have JpaAdvertiseCacheRepositoryImpl which is a custom repository implementation of SpringDataJpa. I need this for a complicated criteria.

I managed to do filter criterias via Predicates and pagination via TypedQuery.

My big issue now is Sorting! Could not find a way to do this in custom implementation of repo.

Anybody knows how to do that?

Tnx

```
public class JpaAdvertiseCacheRepositoryImpl implements JpaAdvertiseCacheRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<AdvertiseCacheJpa> findByFilter(FilterBuilder filter) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<AdvertiseCacheJpa> query = builder.createQuery(AdvertiseCacheJpa.class);
        Root<AdvertiseCacheJpa> from = query.from(AdvertiseCacheJpa.class);

        //apply filter <- applyFilter returns array of predicates
        Predicate[] predicates = applyFilter(filter, builder, from);

        if (predicates.length > 0) {
            //query.where(builder.and(predicates));
            query.where(predicates);
        }

       //apply sorting <- THIS HAVE TO WORK SOON :)
        Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "price");
       //query.orderBy()

       //apply pagination
       TypedQuery typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
       typedQuery = typedQuery.setFirstResult(filter.getOffset());
       typedQuery = typedQuery.setMaxResults(filter.getMaxItemsPerPage());
       return typedQuery.getResultList();
      //return  em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If AdvertiseCacheJpa model contains "price" field (it is unknown from which model it is from this part of code), should be something like this:

Also, CriteriaBuilder don't know anything about Spring's Sort object, so you can not use it directly here.

Instead of

```java
//apply sorting <- THIS HAVE TO WORK SOON :)
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "price");
//query.orderBy()
```

use this

```java
query.orderBy(builder.asc(from.get("price")));
```